# Finding a probability on an infinite set of numbers

Tags: probability

I have $\Omega={1,2,3,...}$ and the possibility of each number is $P(A) = 2^{-n}$, $n=1,2,3...$
I have to prove $P(\Omega) = 1$ . I can understand that from the graph, but how do I actually prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the Geometric Series formula.

$P(\Omega)= \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{2^n}= \frac { \frac{1}{2}}{1- \frac{1}{2}}= 1$

Comment: thank you. I knew this is the solution, dont understand how to solve it, Ill search it now, maybe, if u can, u can give me some links to understand it.

Comment: Which part are you not understanding?

Comment: I dont know how to actually solve the formula. How do I get this result?

Comment: @CnewbieWannabePro: $P(\Omega)= \sum_{n=1}^ \infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac12 + \sum_{n=2}^ \infty \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac12 +\frac12 P(\Omega)$ which is easy to solve

Comment: @CnewbieWannabePro If you want to read further, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula

Answer (score 0):

$P(Ω) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} P(n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 2^{-n} = \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2^2}+\frac{1}{2^3} + ..... = \frac{1/2}{1-1/2} =1 $

Answer (score 0):

Summation of 1/2^k as k goes to infinity is 1..